# How to merge two existing roles to a single user - wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have two plugins and each one has a different role for the user. I want that when admin approves the user in a role, he is automatically assigned to another role.
I'm thinking of doing this in function.php

I tried to create a function, but it didn't work. I tried to put plugins, but in addition to getting heavy, none that I tested makes this role junction automatic

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_secondary_role', 10, 1 );
function add_secondary_role( $user_id ) {
$user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

if (userpro()) {
    $user_id->userpro = true;
    $user->add_role('manager');
}
}
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ricardo Groiso The [add_user_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_user_role/) action hook is triggered after a role is assigned. The hook passes the `$user_id` and `$role` (string). In your hook function use the `$user_id` to get the [user object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/). With the user object you can [assign a new role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_role/) to the user. If you need help with code, please post what you have tried.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_secondary_role', 10, 1 );
function add_secondary_role( $user_id ) {
$user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

if (userpro()) {
 $user_id->userpro = true;
 $user->add_role('manager');
}
}

Comment: @Ricardo Groiso Can you provide details about what your plugins are doing? What does *when admin approves the user in a role* mean? Is this happening in the core WordPress admin user profile edit page, or is this happening in a plugin? If it is in a plugin, what actions are triggered? Does the plugin provide any action hooks to help you? Is it possible you need to set your `add_action()` priority to a value lower than the ones used by other plugins so your actions execute later in the firing order?

Comment: OK,
The plugins are: Tutor LMS and WCFM
A user when registered and enters the role of "Subscriber". When he decides (not mandatory) to want to be an "Instructor", he does so via a button requesting to be an "Instructor".
Admin receives this request and approves it or not, if he approves the Tutor LMS adds the role of "Instructor" (it has two roles: "Subscriber" and "Instructor"). When he is given the role of "Instructor" I want him to be given the role of "Manager".

Comment: ...
Purpose: The user, when he is an "Instructor", can and must manage his courses and subscriptions (WCFM) of his clients.
The WCFM control panel only opens for the "Manager" role
Instructor = tutor_instructor
Manager = shop_manager